# Вывод COUNT в массиве

Tags: php, sql, count

Задача: есть несколько столбцов nam1, nam2 - в них цифры от 1 до 30, которые повторяются.

Необходимо посчитать количество повторений каждого числа и вывести результат в две колонки - число, количество повторений. Имеем запись следующего типа:

```
$query="SELECT nam1, COUNT(*) AS total FROM lottoindex WHERE nam1 > 0 GROUP BY nam1";   

    $rs = mysql_query($query);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
       echo $rs;

       echo $row['nam1'];
       echo '<br>';
    }
```

Выводит результат:

```
Resource id #5 1
Resource id #5 10
Resource id #5 11
Resource id #5 12
...
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема и как сделать правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   echo $rs;

   echo $row['nam1'];
   echo '<br>';
```

замените на

```
   echo $row['nam1'];

   echo $row['total'];
   echo '<br>';
```

Comment: Все верно, но считает только со столбца nam1 как сделать что бы отображало типа Число1 = nam1 + nam2 ...